# Shell.Run full screen

Tags: javascript, intranet, hta

Is it possible, using Javascript, to make Shell.Run call a full-screen batch file on Windows 7?
I'm using this on a HTA file.

I've succesfully called the batch file using the command below

```
function fn_exrel(wprogram) 
{
WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run("\\\\server01\\programs\\contab\\" + wprogram + ".exe",1,true);                
window.open("http://server01/decon/cgi-bin/" + wprogram + "h.exe","_blank");            
}
```

According to this article, there is no option for fullscreen:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky(v=vs.84).aspx

Thank you for the help.

Comment: When the exe has a commandLine-option for fullscreen you may add this option to the path of the exe

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this after the window.open call:

```
WshShell.SendKeys "{F11}"
```

Comment: I got some things messed up, as you can see in the code is an exe not a batch file as i mentioned. Also i see no options on the EXE to open it on fullscreen, also tried creating a shortcut - to no avail. The SendKeys did not work (as there is no fullscreen command to it).

Comment: I'm sorry, I assumed you opened a webpage when I saw the window.location call